per-instruction instruction counts on linux?
If I run my program under perf on linux, it will easily give me the total count of instructions executed. Is it possible to somehow (maybe also with perf but that's not a requirement) get a count of instructions executed, broken down by instruction? e.g. it might look like this (but with presumably many more instructions and much higher numbers)
      8 cmp
      4 mov
      3 jne
      2 xor
      2 shr
      2 ret
      2 jb
      2 jae
      1 movzx
      1 jmp
      1 inc
      1 cmovb
      1 add

my motivation is to diff the outputs for two versions of a program as one angle of analyzing performance differences.

maybe Intel Pin? Either case it'll be extremely inefficient to count individual instructions

@phuclv: Intel SDE (based on Pin) can give you a per-instruction histogram.  How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown?, which I think might be a duplicate.  libsvm compiled with AVX vs no AVX has an example of the output text file.

If I understand you correctly then what you're seeking to do (a kind of "timed code coverage") is sometimes called "control flow tracing"; at least the Intel Processor Trace docs, https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Perf_tools_support_for_Intel%C2%AE_Processor_Trace call it that. See the HelloWorld example there.
To do this automatically / low-overhead, hardware support for a form of "instruction flow recording" is needed. On x86 platforms, that'd be the mentioned PT, on ARM, PTM (Processor Trace Macrocell) is similar but not commonly available.
The biggest disadvantage is usually that you're limited in how big a codeblock you can trace that way, since the amount of trace data generated is large.
(whether what you're trying to do, count instructions / aggregate time per instruction, is meaningful in one way or the other, that's a different discussion. I'm not attempting to elaborate on that here)
EDIT: Since something might've been misunderstood per the comment here ... actual example:
$ sudo perf record -e intel_pt/cyc=1/u  /bin/echo "This is as test"
This is as test
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.043 MB perf.data ]

Then postprocess it using:
perf script -F dso,sym,symoff,ip,insn --insn-trace --xed

Note the --xed flag. That only works if you install the Intel xed disassembler library and its examples (one of which is the xed command itself) first. You can leave it out, and just see the "raw" binary opcodes instead. I have not found a way to make it print both (decoded instructions and opcodes), please comment if you know.
The first perf record instructs perf to use Intel PT branch tracing (all branches is default, but you can configure), and the second perf script to reconstruct the instruction sequence from that.
Sample of the output is something like this:
...
     63d58fc19618 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %eax, %eax
     63d58fc1961a [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jz 0x63d58fc19c6b
     63d58fc19620 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             lea 0x40ca(%rip), %rsi
     63d58fc19627 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov %r12, %rdi
     63d58fc1962a [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             callq  0x63d58fc193b0
     63d58fc193b0 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             nop %edi, %edx
     63d58fc193b4 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jmpq  0x6b76(%rip)
     7a7d1538af90 __strcmp_avx2+0x0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               nop %edi, %edx
     7a7d1538af94 __strcmp_avx2+0x4 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               vpxor %xmm15, %xmm15, %xmm15
     7a7d1538af99 __strcmp_avx2+0x9 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               mov %edi, %eax
     7a7d1538af9b __strcmp_avx2+0xb (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               or %esi, %eax
     7a7d1538af9d __strcmp_avx2+0xd (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               shl $0x14, %eax
     7a7d1538afa0 __strcmp_avx2+0x10 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              cmp $0xf8000000, %eax
     7a7d1538afa5 __strcmp_avx2+0x15 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              jnbe 0x7a7d1538b2d0
     7a7d1538afab __strcmp_avx2+0x1b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vmovdquy  (%rdi), %ymm0
     7a7d1538afaf __strcmp_avx2+0x1f (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vpcmpeqby  (%rsi), %ymm0, %ymm1
     7a7d1538afb3 __strcmp_avx2+0x23 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vpcmpeqb %ymm0, %ymm15, %ymm2
     7a7d1538afb7 __strcmp_avx2+0x27 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vpandn %ymm1, %ymm2, %ymm1
     7a7d1538afbb __strcmp_avx2+0x2b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vpmovmskb %ymm1, %ecx
     7a7d1538afbf __strcmp_avx2+0x2f (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              inc %ecx
     7a7d1538afc1 __strcmp_avx2+0x31 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              jz 0x7a7d1538b020
     7a7d1538afc3 __strcmp_avx2+0x33 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              tzcnt %ecx, %ecx
     7a7d1538afc7 __strcmp_avx2+0x37 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              movzxb  (%rdi,%rcx,1), %eax
     7a7d1538afcb __strcmp_avx2+0x3b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              movzxb  (%rsi,%rcx,1), %ecx
     7a7d1538afcf __strcmp_avx2+0x3f (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              sub %ecx, %eax
     7a7d1538afd1 __strcmp_avx2+0x41 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              vzeroupper
     7a7d1538afd4 __strcmp_avx2+0x44 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)              retq  
     63d58fc1962f [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %eax, %eax
     63d58fc19631 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jz 0x63d58fc19b76
     63d58fc19637 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             lea 0x8(%rbx), %r13
     63d58fc1963b [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov $0x1, %r12d
     63d58fc19641 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %r14d, %r14d
     63d58fc19644 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jnz 0x63d58fc19709
     63d58fc19709 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov $0x20100000001, %r9
     63d58fc19713 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %r15, %r15
     63d58fc19716 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov %r14d, %r12d
     63d58fc19719 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov $0x1, %r14d
     63d58fc1971f [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             setnz %r11b
     63d58fc19723 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             xor %r10d, %r10d
     63d58fc19726 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             movq  (%r13), %r8
     63d58fc1972a [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             cmpb  $0x2d, (%r8)
     63d58fc1972e [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jnz 0x63d58fc19bcd
     63d58fc19bcd [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %r11b, %r11b
     63d58fc19bd0 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jnz 0x63d58fc19659
     63d58fc19bd6 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             test %r10b, %r10b
     63d58fc19bd9 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jz 0x63d58fc19a93
     63d58fc19a93 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             mov %r12d, %r12d
     63d58fc19a96 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             movq  0x652b(%rip), %rbx
     63d58fc19a9d [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             lea (%r13,%r12,8), %r12
     63d58fc19aa2 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jmp 0x63d58fc19ab3
     63d58fc19ab3 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             movq  (%r13), %rdi
     63d58fc19ab7 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             movq  (%rbx), %rsi
     63d58fc19aba [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             add $0x8, %r13
     63d58fc19abe [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             callq  0x63d58fc193a0
     63d58fc193a0 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             nop %edi, %edx
     63d58fc193a4 [unknown] (/usr/bin/echo)             jmpq  0x6b7e(%rip)
     7a7d152917a0 __GI___fputs_unlocked+0x0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)               nop %edi, %edx
...

To my reading, this is what the original poster asked for; how to postprocess this into "histograms" I leave as an exercise to the reader.

Was this answer generated with an AI? It completely misses the point. With PT you cannot get an instruction histogram, AFAIK no perf tool can do that. You need an instrumentation tool, like PIN, SDE, or DynamoRIO. Or just run your test in single-step mode and use a 3rd library to decode each instruction at each step.

You can - but indirectly. The branch points (and those you get from PT) together with the disassembled code give you the codeflow, instruction-by-instruction, and that (as said, indirectly) gives you instruction counts. And no, I do not use AI.

@MargaretBloom there is an (old) conference presentation, "Efficient and Large Scale Program Flow Tracing in Linux", http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcna13_kleen.pdf that talks about this. As said, raw data is not "down to instruction", since PT/perf will only record you the branch history, so to do stats for the instructions "between", you'll need to postprocess.

@MargaretBloom: Branch history is enough to know which basic blocks ran how many times, which is sufficient to reconstruct the instruction mix.  But yes you need tools to do that, and you're probably right that perf itself doesn't include any.  On x86 I'd use Intel's SDE which is based on Pin, as in How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown? .  For an example of its instruction histogram, see libsvm compiled with AVX vs no AVX
